# Angularjs Jquery memory leak

Tags: jquery, angularjs, memory-leaks

My web application is developed using the jQuery and Angularjs.

I am searching for pattern which would cause memory leak in angularjs.

Tools to find memory leak. chrome profiler is good, but didnt find any example using angularjs.

Any angular specific tutorial which will help me to find & fix the memory leak. Pattern in angularjs which would cause memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

Some to get you started:

- [Running from AngularJS Memory Leaks](https://medium.com/@meanjim/running-from-angularjs-memory-leaks-3a12a711c7ec)
- Chrome extension: [Angular watchers](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angular-watchers/nlmjblobloedpmkmmckeehnbfalnjnjk/related) to track the number of watchers. If it keeps going up when it shouldn't, that's one form of leak (it may indicate scopes not being destroyed when they should be).
- You can steal my `gl.debugutils` module from [this Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/oZpJE9csEQy6oOmgP0x5) - just take the `debugUtils.js` file. It is not foolproof, but it does allow you to display a decent breakdown of statistics about watches inside your app. To use it, type `printWatchStats()` on the console.
- Learn how to decipher the Record Heap Allocations profile in Chrome devtools.